# Layering canvas objects in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, sorting, fabricjs, layer

Is there a way to layer objects on a Fabric.js canvas via the official API? Right now the only way I have found to do it is to manually iterate through the canvas._objects and reorder them so that they get drawn in a specific order. Is there a better way to do this that doesn't (potentially) break the object?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

[Edit]
I've corrected my info below (my bad, I was originally thinking of the KineticJs api).

FabricJS has these API methods that change the z-index of objects:

```
canvas.sendBackwards(myObject)
canvas.sendToBack(myObject)
canvas.bringForward(myObject)
canvas.bringToFront(myObject)
```

Under the covers, FabricJs changes the z-index by removing the object from the getObjects() array and splicing it back in the desired position.  It has a nice optimization that checks for intersecting objects.

```
bringForward: function (object) {
       var objects = this.getObjects(),
           idx = objects.indexOf(object),
           nextIntersectingIdx = idx;


       // if object is not on top of stack (last item in an array)
       if (idx !== objects.length-1) {

         // traverse up the stack looking for the nearest intersecting object
         for (var i = idx + 1, l = this._objects.length; i < l; ++i) {

           var isIntersecting = object.intersectsWithObject(objects[i]) ||
                                object.isContainedWithinObject(this._objects[i]) ||
                                this._objects[i].isContainedWithinObject(object);

           if (isIntersecting) {
             nextIntersectingIdx = i;
             break;
           }
         }
         removeFromArray(objects, object);
         objects.splice(nextIntersectingIdx, 0, object);
       }
       this.renderAll();
     },
```

Comment: Thank you! This saves me a lot of trouble.

Comment: does fabricjs have a built-in object stack index system ... then I could do  something like `var idx = some_object.get_zIndex()`

Comment: You can get the z-index: canvas.getObjects().indexOf(some_object).  Four commands are available to change the stacking order: some_object.sendBackwards(), some_object.sendToBack(), some_object.bringForward(), and some_object.bringToFront().

Comment: ahh geez, of course ... if it was a snake it would have bit me ... thanks.

Comment: @markE   ???=canvas.getObjects().indexOf(Obj])+1;  , how to change z-ndex position using these method?

Comment: @simmisimmi. You use these canvas methods to affect the z-index of objects in relation to other objects: bringToFront(object) bringFoward(object) sendToBack(object) sendBackwards(object). Both sendBackwards and bringForward accept a second object that you want to index relative to.

Comment: Using markE suggestion worked for me.  I had a line that needed to be behind everything except one object.  This worked: canvas.sendToBack(aLine);
canvas.bringForward(aLine, bg_group);

Answer (score 8):

step 1 : You can Use `preserveObjectStacking: true`

step 2 : then use sendtoback,sendtofront....fabricjs options like below

[Answered over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41879620/1390678)

Answer (score 4):

This is how I did it. I added a zIndex property to every fabric object and then called a sort function after they were added to the canvas:

```
const CIRCLE_INDEX = 1
let object = new fabric.Circle({
    left: 10,
    top: 10,
    radius: 5
    ...other properties
    zIndex: CIRCLE_INDEX
});
```

And then call a function like this after you added your objects

```
const sortObjects = () => {
    canvas._objects.sort((a, b) => (a.zIndex > b.zIndex) ? 1 : -1);
    canvas.renderAll();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set a specific ordering for all objects, instead of moving one object forward/backward, iterative calls to bring/send to front/back are slow.

You can use the code of `bringToFront` as inspiration to speed this use case up: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/blob/586e61dd282b22c1d50e15c0361875707e526fd8/src/static_canvas.class.js#L1468

And do this:

```
fabric.Canvas.prototype.orderObjects = function(compare) {
    this._objects.sort(compare);
    this.renderAll();
}
```

Where compare defines the sorting, like:

```
function compare(x,y) {
    return x.getWidth() * x.getHeight() < y.getWidth() * y.getHeight();
}

some_canvas.orderObjects(compare)
```

If you wish to bring smaller objects to the front.